# Current electricity confusion

Tags: electricity

If we connect a voltmeter without having any internal resistance across two points to measure potential difference then will there be any current flowing through the wire to which voltmeter is connected...I think there should be some current since only resistance of the wire is zero and not the potential difference across the voltmeter 
 i.e delta V=or but only R of the wire connected to the voltmeter is zero but 'I' could be anything but this would always then give delta V=0 which is wrong since it already measure the potential difference between the external resistance.... I hope you understand my confusion...Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please try to reword your question using short sentences with very clear modifying phrases. It is unclear whether the meter or the wire has zero resistance. It is unclear what concept you are confused about.

Answer (score 1):

If the internal resistance of a voltmeter is 0 (considering that it is possible) then all the current will pass through the voltmeter and damage it. There will be no current through the wire of resistance R across which potential drop is measured.

This is a case of short circuiting. Current chooses the path in which resistance is minimum and if resistance is 0 then all the current would like to go through that path.

Also, the potential drop across two points in the connecting wire is 0 given no electronic component is between them.

Although an ideal voltmeter has infinite resistance which enables the voltmeter to get as accurate reading as possible. Infinite resistance would allow only a very small amount of current to pass through it and hence leave the circuit under consideration undisturbed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a volt meter has a very high resistance. The higher the better. An ideal volt meter would have infinite resistance, this is to prevent current from  passing through the volt meter which will mess up your experiment.

Secondly, you don't need to have current to have a voltage drop ($\Delta V$). You can imagine electricity as water flowing through pipes. The voltage is the pressure and the current is how much water is flowing through the pipe. A positive voltage is a positive pressure (pushing) and a negative voltage negative pressure (sucking). The voltage you measure 'across' something is $ \text{pressure before} - \text{pressure after}$. In both cases the voltage represents some energy level of whatever is flowing.

If you insert something that blocks the current (like a valve), you stop the current. The voltage remains the same though. The valve represents a resistor with $R=\infty$ and the voltage is still the difference in pressure. If you open the valve a little, water starts to flow through the valve. How much depends on the new value of $R$. You can calculate $R$ by measuring the voltage drop $\Delta V$, which represents how much energy is lost in the valve, and dividing it by the current.

Hope this will give you a little more intuition in electricity.